# Text size in xfig not working in Ubuntu version 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04. While trying `xfig`, I found out that the text size does not change. No matter what number I feed into it and set it, the output is always size 12.

Answer (score 2):

Install the package `gsfonts-x11`, e.g. with:

```
sudo apt-get install gsfonts-x11
```

and restart your computer. Then it should work.